# npm install running failed

Tags: node.js, gulp

[image]

Even though I use Administrator install gulp, it still failed.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: it seem like your `package-lock.json` is read-only, remove or change permission for that file

Comment: I checked it's not read-only...

Comment: Could you please add the code as text rather than an image? That would make the error message searchable and easier to find for someone else that might have the problem.

Comment: Please add the code as text rather than the image. Include the command that you ran which lead to this error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permission of the file and for more information about permission visit
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 0):

If you are in China, there's some network problem to install node-sass.

you can try to use this command to install node: `SASS_BINARY_SITE=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-sass/ npm install node-sass --save-dev`